# How to make progress bar in webpage for dropdownlist box

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm just invoking the data from excel sheet to drop down list box .
it s taking around 5 sec to invoke till that can I  make progress bar to run in UI.is this is possible

Comment: Ofc you can https://jqueryui.com/progressbar/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until you get the response you can put a waiting dialog..
after getting the response you can hide the dialog..
Here is a link of simple dialog using jquery [waitingDialog](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/Oe5XM)

And this dialog can be best used with angular so good luck..

Comment: hi when im using waiting dialog its executing after function call.

Comment: waitingDialog.show('I\'m waiting');
 fetchVariable();
/* DateSplitting */
 dateSplitting();
 
/* AccessExcel Sheet */
 accessExcel(); 
 waitingDialog.hide();
 /* SQL*/
 
 /*  InsertAccess(); */